# list comprehension to create n unique copies of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, deep-copy

I have two lists of dictionary keys:  a list of 'outer' dictionary keys, and a list of 'inner' dictionary keys:

```
outer_keys = ['out1', 'out2', 'out3', 'out4' ]
inner_keys = ['in1', 'in2', 'in3' ]
```

I am trying to use a list comprehension to programmatically generate nested dictionaries resembling the following structure:

```
{'out1': {'in1': Decimal('0.00'), 'in2': Decimal('0.00'), 'in3': Decimal('0.00')},
 'out2': {'in1': Decimal('0.00'), 'in2': Decimal('0.00'), 'in3': Decimal('0.00')},
 'out3': {'in1': Decimal('0.00'), 'in2': Decimal('0.00'), 'in3': Decimal('0.00')},
 'out4': {'in1': Decimal('0.00'), 'in2': Decimal('0.00'), 'in3': Decimal('0.00')}
}
```

My first attempt was the following:

```
from decimal import Decimal
outer_keys = ['out1', 'out2', 'out3', 'out4' ]
inner_keys = ['in1', 'in2', 'in3' ]

z = dict(zip(outer_keys, [dict(zip(inner_keys, [Decimal('0.00') for _ in inner_keys])) for _ in outer_keys]))
```

This works properly, in the sense that the 'inner' dictionaries referenced by the 'outer' keys are all unique:

```
>>> z['out1']['in1'] is z['out2']['in1']
False
```

However, the assignment to z is fairly difficult to follow.  So I tried breaking it up into two assignments to simplify it:

```
x = dict(zip(inner_keys, [Decimal('0.00') for _ in inner_keys]))
y = dict(zip(outer_keys, [x for _ in outer_keys]))
```

This no longer works because the values of the 'outer' keys 'out1', ..., 'out4' all reference the same dictionary.

```
>>> y['out1']['in1'] is y['out2']['in1']
True
```

So assigning to an item in one inner dictionary changes the corresponding value in them all:

```
>>> y['out1']['in1']
Decimal('0.00')
>>> y['out2']['in1']
Decimal('0.00')
>>> y['out1']['in1']=Decimal('1.00')
>>> y['out2']['in1']
Decimal('1.00')
>>>
```

I've tried using everything I can think of in place of `x` in the list comprehension in the assignment to `y` (including, e.g., `copy.deepcopy(x)` and a list-slice like `[x][:][0]`, but no matter what I do, I cannot get python to create a unique copy of the dictionary referenced by x for each outer key value.  Except of course by going back to the original lengthy and unreadable assignment to z.

I'm also having trouble understanding why `[Decimal('0.00') for _ in inner_keys]` generates three unique Decimal objects, but `[x for _ in outer_keys]` generates four references to a single dict.  And how to write a list comprehension which will generate *n* unique copies of the dict `x`.

Edit 1:  It seems I wasn't careful enough in checking whether some of things I tried were actually working.  As @MichaelButscher correctly points out in his comment below, using `x.copy()` rather than `x` in the assignment to `y` will resolve my issue, as so it seems did `copy.deepcopy(x)` even though I didn't realize it was working.

So that is certainly one way I could fix this.

I also like the dict comprehension solution that @Ahmed I. Elsayed posted below.

Both of these are much cleaner than my original complicated assignment to `z`

Comment: dict objects have their own "copy" method for a (shallow) copy which is enough here for the inner dictionaries. So you only have to create a prototype inner dictionary and copy it. And the Decimal objects aren't unique but they are immutable so it doesn't matter if the same is present multiple times.

Comment: @MichaelButscher  I also tried `[x.copy() for _ in outer_keys]` .  That also fails in the same way:  
`>>> y = dict(zip(outer_keys, [x.copy() for _ in outer_keys]))  
>>> y['out1']['in1'] is y['out2']['in1']  
True  
`

Comment: @stacker This last check in your comments checks identity of Decimal objects, not the dict. As I said it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MichaelButscher  ok.  I tried it again with x.copy() and it seems to work after all.  I guess my test wasn't checking what I thought it was checking.  I thought I had also checked that after  
`y['out1']['in1'] += Decimal('999.00')`  
that `y['out2']['in1']` had also changed.  
But checking again, it seems not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python offers dict comprehensions (and set comps too!)

```
# IDLE ( I reformatted )

my_dict = { key: inner_keys for key in outer_keys }
my_dict

{
 'out1': ['in1', 'in2', 'in3'],
 'out2': ['in1', 'in2', 'in3'],
 'out3': ['in1', 'in2', 'in3'],
 'out4': ['in1', 'in2', 'in3']
}
```

if you want to apply something to the second list like you've used `Decimal`, Multiple ways

```
my_dict = { key: [i.upper() for i in inner_keys ] for key in outer_keys }
my_dict

{
 'out1': ['IN1', 'IN2', 'IN3'],
 'out2': ['IN1', 'IN2', 'IN3'],
 'out3': ['IN1', 'IN2', 'IN3'],
 'out4': ['IN1', 'IN2', 'IN3']
}
```

or

```
my_dict = { key: map(str.upper, inner_keys) for key in outer_keys }
# same output as above, trimmed for readability
```

customize as needed, or ask in the comments here.

I'd like to credit where I learnt *dictcomps*, The first time I saw them were in the awesome book [*Fluent Python*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491946008) by the genius Luciano Ramalho.

Comment: `z = { k1 : { k2:Decimal('0.00') for k2 in inner_keys } for k1 in outer_keys }`  
appears to do the trick.  Thanks!  I think it's much more readable than my original assignment to `z`.

Comment: I suggest reading the book too, It will generously help, Mark as answered if this helped. Have a nice day.